# Debugger are not making array

Tags: debugging, keil

I write a code, and run it on debugger.
I make a simple array (one complex and other float), but the debugger not recognize them.

[Code +debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSfSh.jpg)

Comment: Are you getting into the while loop in the first place?

Comment: Yes, everything work perfect except the size of the debugger (even the printf, print the second and third variable, but the debugger not showing them)